# cloop-utils for CentOS

Tags: centos

I would like to edit live CD's. Reading http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7246?page=0,0, I need the extract_compressed_fs executable. I couldn't find the package in the default yum repository, on the net (RPM for CentOS/RHEL) or the source code package. Where can I find it?

Using CentOS 6.2, minimal install.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using squashfs for remastering clonezilla, no "extract_compressed_fs" is required. Note that on CentOS 6.2, the squashfs package from the repository doesn't support XZ compression, so you must download and compile it (edit makefile to enable XZ).